# How to make ScriptEngine to run multiple javascript files?

Tags: java, javascript, scriptengine

I have 6 js files and I need to include them all into final script to pass ScriptEngine's eval method.How can I do it? ScriptEngine haven't add() method.I can read them with FileReader and than concatenate those strings but I think there will be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the overload [`eval(Reader)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval%28java.io.Reader%29) to avoid having to load scripts into a `String` yourself.

Comment: I have 6 files.And i need to add them all before calling eval.

Comment: @Ademiban Can't you call eval() multiple times?

Comment: No some of my js-es are using functions from others.

Comment: You were right :D sorry... if I call eval multiple times ScriptEngine keeps functions and variables from last calls.thanks ))

Comment: @shift66 are you able to call one js function from another file,can you please post the code.

Comment: @Coded9 Please don’t resurrect ancient comment exchanges. If you’re facing a problem this answer doesn’t address, post a new question that describes it appropriately. That said, doing what I said in my answer did let shift66 call functions across files, so it should be possible for you - just call eval() on all your JS sources using the same `ScriptEngine` instance.

Comment: @millimoose that works  for me ,but here I'm using ext js ,it is throwing errors when loading the files

Comment: @Coded9 Did you miss the part where I said to post a new, proper question? It is **very** bad form to cling on whoever pays you any attention, and be lazy at explaining your problem because you assume that its similarity to this five-year old question means I’ll read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one script to call the other 6 scripts.

Example:

```
function callOtherFunctions() {
   functionOne();
   functionTwo();
   .
   .
   .
   functionSix();
}
```

Not 100% sure how good that solution will work but it will call all other 6 functions.

Comment: You don't understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Run eval multiple times using the same ScriptContext.

In the next example I need to run Utils.js script before running MainScript.js because Utils.js is defining some functions I need in MainScript.js, I always think of this order as the way these scripts will appear in an HTML page of I were to execute this in a browser:

```
    String scriptsUtilsFilePath = "src/test/resources/scripts/Utils.js";
    String mainScriptFilePath = "src/test/resources/scripts/MainScript.js";

    // Get the script engine manager
    ScriptContext newContext = new SimpleScriptContext();
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");// Newest Javascript engine

    // Run Utils
    engine.eval(new FileReader(scriptsUtilsFilePath), newContext);

    // Run the Main Script
    engine.eval(new FileReader(mainScriptFilePath), newContext);
```